# CodeIgniter 2.0.2 syntax error blank page

Tags: codeigniter, syntax, reporting

CodeIgniter 2.0.2 syntax error blank page

i have CodeIgniter 2.0.2 (CI) and its annoing, that when i write lots of code and then just get blank page. Hard to debug without error. i got error reporting E_ALL in php.ini and in config of CI its turned on for every case of enviroment (devel, product) just for sure... 
Does anyone knows, where the bug can be? How to turn it on? I think CI is rewriting php.ini error reporting setting somewhere somehow...

Thanks.

Comment: in php.ini i had good settings of error_reporting, but display_errors had value Off, turned it On and no more white pages... thanks guys for help.... problem solved...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other thing to check in your php.ini are the 'display_errors' and 'display_startup_errors' variables, they should both be set to 1.

Answer (score 3):

In my (little) experience with CI this issue has been the most frustating one. I can understand that no framework is perfect, and any web developer is used to deal with errors (no matter if the framework or the developer is to blame). But that ANY error results in a blank page, with ZERO information in logs, console, whatever, is unacceptable.

If I recall correctly, in my case this was caused by of some combination of CI (ab)using the "silent error" PHP operator (e.g. prepending some db statements with the `@` operator, a not very clever way of avoiding leaking potentially private information to the end user), together with some bad use of *error_reporting*.  See [my post here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/189001/) (and see how many answers I got!).

I reported another related CI's <s>idiocy</s>idiosyncrasy related with logging [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/104365/) (again, zero answers)

Answer (score 2):

please check the `index.php` which locate in the SAME LEVEL of the application folder
inside the `index.php` the second line

line 2:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1");  //ensure it is set to 1
```

line 23:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development'); // development | testing | production
```

grep your `php.ini` for the word "error", turn them to On etc...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have output compression turned on in the config? I find that will cause white pages when you have errors.

```
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE; // Should be set to this when developing.
```

Comment: i got turned it off by default, as you pasted. Still white pages.

Comment: i tried phpinfo(); to see what it says i found few interresting lines, but dont know what to do...<br/><br/>
display_errors Off Off
error_reporting 30719 32767
html_errors Off Off

Comment: I just posted another answer about this actually - I think it's a display_errors issue based on what you just said.

Comment: in php.ini i had good settings of error_reporting, but display_errors had value Off, turned it On and no more white pages... thanks guys for help.... problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and eventually fixed it when i noticed I had no 'logs' directory in my application folder